# MySql Sorting complications

Tags: mysql, sorting

I came across a scenario where i have values in a coloumn like

```
Buno foo
Buno this
Buno that
Buno bar
```

This is the values of a single coloumn,Now i want to sort this coloumn excluding the

> Buno

word,means sorting should be applied on foo,this,that and bar.Is there a way to do this in MySql?

Comment: Substring would be the place to start...

Comment: @OMGPonies How to do that in mysql?

Comment: SO is not for doing it for you, SO is for help.  What have you tried?  Have you looked at MySQL string functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select * from tableName order by Column_Name

This query can get you the required results, you dont have to worry about the first word.

database query sorts on the first word, if the first word is same, then its sorts according to the second word.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, using ORDER BY will sort the entire value in the column, not just the first word, so you should just be able to use ORDER BY to solve your problem...

If you wanted to remove the first section though, you would need to use SUBSTRING in your SELECT and then ORDER BY your substring...

EDIT: Saw your comment above on not knowing how to use SUBSTRING, here is an example using your data:

SELECT SUBSTRING('Buno Foo', 5) AS NOBuno FROM MyTable ORDER BY NOBuno ASC

Answer (score 1):

You can extract the substring of your column from the 6th character onwards (since you always have `Buno` at the front, which is 5 characters long). To do this use [`SUBSTRING`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring):

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(my_column FROM 6)
```

Note that `SELECT SUBSTRING(my_column FROM 6)` will return `foo`,`this`,`that`, etc.

If you wanted to be a bit more general and order using the second word, you can try [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index). (read the docs and you'll work it out).